# Remove row if term found in a CSV column

Tags: powershell

I need to remove a row from a table if I find a certain kind of email address in my CSV table. There are multiple email fields but I only want to do this for one email column, not any which is what I think the code below would currently do.

How can I specify that?

```
$data = foreach ($line in Get-Content D:\Data\info.csv) {
    if ($line -Like '*@LS*' -or $line -Like '*@gmail*') {
    } else {
        $line
    }
}
$data | Set-Content D:\Data\info.csv -Force
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-3.0) filter:

```
$file = 'D:\Data\info.csv'
(Get-Content $file) | Where-Object {
    $_ -notlike '*@LS*' -and $_ -notlike '*@gmail*'
} | Set-Content $file
```

If you want to check a particular field instead of the entire line use `Import-Csv`/`Export-Csv` instead of `Get-Content`/`Set-Content`:

```
$file = 'D:\Data\info.csv'
(Import-Csv $file) | Where-Object {
    $_.FOO -notlike '*@LS*' -and $_.FOO -notlike '*@gmail*'
} | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

Replace `FOO` with the actual field name.

Instead of the wildcard matches you could also use string operations:

```
-not $_.FOO.Contains('@LS') -and -not $_.FOO.Contains('@gmail')
```

or a single regular expression:

```
$_.FOO -notmatch '@(LS|gmail)'
```

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Ansgar Wiechers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55287949/45375):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) allows for a concise solution (PSv3+ syntax) with *whole-line* matching - as advised by Ansgar, using `Import-Csv` and limiting matching to the field of interest is preferable:

```
(Select-String -NotMatch '@LS', '@gmail' D:\Data\info.csv).Line |
  Set-Content D:\Data\info.csv -Force
```

Note how the `Select-String` call is enclosed in `(...)` to ensure that the input file is processed in full up front, allowing you to write back to the same file in the same pipeline.
Note, however, that that loads all matching lines into memory at once, and that there's a small risk of data loss if writing back to the input file gets interrupted - both issues could be remedied with more effort.